# How did Solange Dimitrios die in Casino Royale?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, casino-royale

I am curious to know who tortured and killed Solange Dimitrios (wife of Alex Dimitrios) in *Casino Royale*. Bond has left her in his hotel room at the night when he went after Alex Dimitrios who was killed by James Bond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it was implied to be [Le-Chiffre](http://jamesbond.wikia.com/wiki/Le_Chiffre_(Mads_Mikkelsen)) because when Bond thwarts the bomb plot he was the one who lost heavily (totaling $101,206,000) because of bond's action since he invested on stocks against the Skyfleet.

Le-Chiffre is shown to be a poker prodigy in the movie I don't think it would've taken him long enough to figure out the loose-ends which might've caused him to lose all the money.